# Type Error in javascript: Cannot read Property of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that loos like this :

```
var usedNums= new Array(76);
function setSquare(thisSquare)
{

    var currSquare = "square"+ thisSquare;
    var colPlace =  new Array(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4);
    var colBasis = colPlace[thisSquare] * 15;

    var newNum;
    do{
      newNum = colBasis + getNewNum() + 1;

    }while(usedNums[newNum]); //UnCaught TypeError here

    usedNums[newNum] = true;
    document.getElementById(currSquare).innerHTML = newNum;
}
```

The error says:

> Can not read property '5' of undefined.

I have checked using console.log statement and all the variables above are getting expected values .

I understand what Type Error is but not sure where is it breaking.

**Edit:**Here is the complete Script:

```
window.onload = new newCard;
var usedNums= new Array(76);

function newCard()
{
  if(document.getElementById){
      for(var i =0; i<24;i++)
      { 
          console.log("Value of I is " + i);
          setSquare(i);

      }
  }else{

   alert("Sorry, your browser does not support this script");
  }
}

function setSquare(thisSquare)
{
    console.log("thissquare" + thisSquare);
    var currSquare = "square"+ thisSquare;
    console.log("currsquare" + currSquare);
    var colPlace =  new Array(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4);
    console.log("colplace" + colPlace);
    var colBasis = colPlace[thisSquare] * 15;
    console.log("colbasis"+ colBasis);
    var newNum;
    do{
      newNum = colBasis + getNewNum() + 1;
      console.log("new nUM" + newNum);
    }while(usedNums[newNum]);

    usedNums[newNum] = true;
    document.getElementById(currSquare).innerHTML = newNum;
}

function getNewNum()
{
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
console.log("random number" + a);
return a;
}
```

Comment: where is the definition of usedNums, because it seems that it's not defined?

Comment: @Vasilev: It is outside of function.Updated the question.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: getNewNum is not defined`  — Please make sure your provide code in the question that actually demonstrates the problem: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @sscce.org:  Error says UnCaught Type Error only.Added getNewNum definition in the question.

Comment: Please provide the code for `getNewNum()`. Providing an example of how you're using this function would be helpful as well.

Comment: @Nick: Added complete script.Please check.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Plase make sure that usedNums is defined properly, check the name again, etc.

Comment: @Vasilev: I have added the complete script. Please have a look.

Comment: Put `window.onload = new newCard;` at the end of your script

Comment: @Michel: That solved the problem but since window.onLoad in called at end ,In that case I get "Can not set property innerHTML of null".

Comment: @Michel: Also, Could you please let me know why was I getting that error when it was at top of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
window.onload = new newCard;
```

is:

1. Invoking `newCard` as a constructor (which it isn't)
2. Assigning the object created from it to `onload`

Since you are invoking `newCard` there, it runs before you reach the next line:

```
var usedNums= new Array(76);
```

So `usedNums` is undefined when you try to read from it.

You need to assign the `newCard` **function** as your load handler. So don't invoke it:

```
window.onload = newCard;
```

Comment: @Quertin: That helped.I am pretty new to javascript. Do you mind commenting on how do we distinguish other functions form constructor in javascript?